# adding website thumbnail to facebook through css (og:image)

Tags: css, facebook, image, stylesheet, thumbnails

I have standard html files with their own style, and use a common css file for different fonts only.  I need to put the FB website thumbnail to all the files through that css.

Is it possible to add the following to the css or .js files? (as there are thousands of html files):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://websitename/image.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add that snippet to the html itself, not the css. Meta tags go into the head of your webpage (between the `<head></head>` tags). There's no way to insert html into a page via a css file.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGraph is some standard - even if you did put it inside your CSS - nobody would know it's there - so no, it can't be done with CSS.

If some website would process the javascript (but facebook hardly would) you could get lucky but the chances are really low so it is not reliable.

However I suggest you to write a little e.g. PHP skript that would run through all the `.html / .htm` files and would rewrite `<head>` with 
`<head> <meta property="og:image" content="http://websitename/image.jpg">`

But I suggest that instead of adding only html, it would be much better if you would add an include script that would contain further cross-files changes. So next time you would need to add something to `<head>` in all your files you would just add it inside your e.g. `my_include.php`

**EDIT:**
I would also recommend you to look at the facebook's developer tool that tells you exactly what it sees when it visits your site:
 `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=YOURSITEURL`